# Append not showing when hover a new droppable items

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, append

[This is the code in a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matanc244/nqmmxrf2/19/)

What I am trying to do is when someone is hover the drop items he will see the append

But the append is not showing on a new items

I added the hover and the append this is the append code

```
$('.mysortable').hover(function() {

$(this).append('<span class="both">BOOKMARK THIS</span>')
    $('.both').animate({opacity: 1.0}) 
}, function(){
    $('.both').fadeOut(300, function(){
        $(this).filter('.both').remove()
    })
});
```

How can I make the append to show also on new items hover?

Comment: Please explain your question a bit more. What is the new item on which append is not working?

Comment: i fixed the link try again

Comment: let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `.on()`

```
$('#sortable').on('mouseover mouseout', '.mysortable', function(event){
  if(event.type == 'mouseover') {
    //call your function here for append
  } else {
    //call your remove function here
  }
})
```

the important thing to note is that `.on()` in jquery provides dynamic binding of events. And as per experience there is no event 'hover' `.on()`, so you got to use two events.
This works like, you have selected a static element #sortable and you are selecting dynamically `.mysortable` elements.

Comment: the counter part of 'mouseover' is 'mouseout'

Comment: i change to this but still dosent works    $('.mysortable').on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.mysortable',    function(event){
  if(event.type == 'mouseover') {
    
    
    $(this).append('<span class="both">BOOKMARK THIS</span>')
        $('.both').animate({opacity: 1.0}) 


  } else {

        $('.both').fadeOut(300, function(){
            $(this).filter('.both').remove()
        })

  }
});

Comment: please use carefully, the element you are binding event on should be static.. In your case use $('#sortable').on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.mysortable', function(even......

Comment: See the difference I used #sortable and not .sortable

Comment: change 'mouseenter' to 'mouseover' and 'mouseleave' to 'mouseout'

This is working now. I checked on your code

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want, but maybe this might help.

```
$('.mysortable').hover(function() {

    $(this).parent().append('<li><span class="both">BOOKMARK THIS</span></li>')
        $('.both').animate({opacity: 1.0}) 
    }, function(){
        $('.both').fadeOut(300, function(){
            $(this).filter('.both').remove()
        })
    });
```